# Digital Signature Verification with itext not working

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am using itext library for verify digitally signed pdf, following example available on https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5 site. I am getting following error while verifying the digitally signed document. Can any one help to resolve this.

```
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256with1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 Signature not available
at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:229)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.initSignature(PdfPKCS7.java:697)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.<init>(PdfPKCS7.java:459)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2420)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2373)
at nic.test.C5_01_SignatureIntegrity.verifySignature(C5_01_SignatureIntegrity.java:24)
at test.ExtractSignInfor.inspectSignature(ExtractSignInfor.java:95)
at test.ExtractSignInfor.inspectSignatures(ExtractSignInfor.java:135)
at test.ExtractSignInfor.main(ExtractSignInfor.java:63)
```

Comment: Could you post the PDF throwing this exception?

Comment: Have you registered BouncyCastle as security provider?

Comment: Yes I have registered BC as security provider.

Comment: Sorry due to org policy I can't share the PDF.

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid I can't help you further.  If you're a paying customer of iText, you can contact support and we could sign an NDA so that we can process this PDF in all security.

Comment: No I am not using comircial version of itext. I will try to create a sample file with sign and will  to share with you.

Comment: @MichaëlDemey Here is the signed document [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1XKjvoeoyPZWnk5bzc5T3VSQUk) ,please have a look and suggest.

Comment: fyi: I'm able to reproduce this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michaël Demey already explained in his answer, iText 5.x currently does not support the algorithm OID in question.

Fortunately, though, iText 5.x mostly relies on the underlying BouncyCastle library for security algorithm support during signature validation and only does very little itself, all that is missing is that iText properly finds the name of the "encryption algorithm" ECDSA (in quotes as it is not really an encryption because there is no parallel decryption) for the OID.

You can add verification support of that OID in iText 5.x (tested in the current SNAPSHOT for 5.5.13) like this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field algorithmNamesField = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.EncryptionAlgorithms.class.getDeclaredField("algorithmNames");
algorithmNamesField.setAccessible(true);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, String> algorithmNames = (HashMap<String, String>) algorithmNamesField.get(null);
algorithmNames.put("1.2.840.10045.4.3.2", "ECDSA");
```

With this addition executed, iText validation

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();

List<String> names = acroFields.getSignatureNames();
for (String name : names) {
   System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
   System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + acroFields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
   System.out.println("Document revision: " + acroFields.getRevision(name) + " of " + acroFields.getTotalRevisions());
   PdfPKCS7 pk = acroFields.verifySignature(name);
   System.out.println("Subject: " + CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
   System.out.println("Document verifies: " + pk.verify());
}
```

shows

> ```
> Signature name: Signature1
> Signature covers whole document: true
> Document revision: 1 of 1
> Subject: {ST=[Rajasthan], C=[India], CN=[Devi Singh Pilwal], O=[Personal]}
> Document verifies: true
> ```

(Test code in [VerifySignature.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/VerifySignature.java#L274) method `testVerifyTestDsp`)

#### Beware...

- The code above uses reflection as the `Map` in question is not public. Depending on your environment, such a solution might not be allowed. In that case you'd have to patch iText accordingly. Furthermore, as the accessed `Map` is not public, the solution might fail in future versions. (This is unlikely as iText 5 is in maintenance mode, but one never knows.)
- This only adds support for *this very OID*. Most likely support for a number of other OIDs can similarly be added but not necessarily for all.
- Furthermore, I have only tested this in a *verification* use case. ECDSA signing might require completely different changes.

Comment: both the replies are correct, accepted this coz provided solution with backward compatibility. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: To Fix: ExceptionConverter: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

Add this line
Security.addProvider(newBouncyCastleProvider());

Answer (score 5):

If you search for the OID that iText chokes on, you'll see that this is "ecdsa-with-sha256":

http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.4.3.2

This is not supported in iText 5. But we did add support for this in iText 7. Try to run this code sample with the latest iText 7 build:

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUT);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);

PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);

for ( String name : acroForm.getFormFields().keySet() ) {
    PdfFormField formField = acroForm.getField(name);
    if (formField != null && formField instanceof PdfSignatureFormField)    {
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signatureUtil.verifySignature(name);
        pkcs7.verify();
        [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For people still using old versions of *iText* library, like *iText 2.1.7*, verification support for ecdsa-with-sha256 algorithm can be, based on mkl's suggestion, added with this code:

```
// Get field with algorithms used in verification.
java.lang.reflect.Field algorithmNamesField = com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.class.getDeclaredField("algorithmNames");
algorithmNamesField.setAccessible(true);

// Add missing algorithm to the map of algorithms.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, String> algorithmNames = (HashMap<String, String>) algorithmNamesField.get(null);
algorithmNames.put("1.2.840.10045.4.3.2", "ECDSA");
```

Other missing algorithms can also be added to the map, using the last line of code above.

Answer (score 0):

Using .net and iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core need this code (using Reflection) for recognize ECDSA:

Add algorithm name to PdfPkcs7 class:

```
Type type = typeof(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPkcs7);
FieldInfo info = type.GetField("_algorithmNames", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
INullValueDictionary<string, string> _algorithmNames = (INullValueDictionary<string, string>)info.GetValue(null);
_algorithmNames["1.2.840.10045.4.3.1"] = "ECDSA";
_algorithmNames["1.2.840.10045.4.3.2"] = "ECDSA";
_algorithmNames["1.2.840.10045.4.3.3"] = "ECDSA";
_algorithmNames["1.2.840.10045.4.3.4"] = "ECDSA";
```

or directly add AlgorithmMap to BouncyCastle

```
Type type = typeof(Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities);
FieldInfo info = type.GetField("AlgorithmMap", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
IDictionary<string, string> AlgorithmMap = (IDictionary<string, string>)info.GetValue(null);
AlgorithmMap["SHA224WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.1"] = "SHA-224withECDSA";
AlgorithmMap["SHA256WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.2"] = "SHA-256withECDSA";
AlgorithmMap["SHA384WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.3"] = "SHA-384withECDSA";
AlgorithmMap["SHA512WITH1.2.840.10045.4.3.4"] = "SHA-512withECDSA";
```